# React Webcam - Take Screenshot Issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm attempting to use the react-webcam module. I'm able to get the webcam video mirrored on the page. However, I'm having issues implementing the getScreenshot function when a button is hit. Does anyone have any advice? Below is my code. Thank you.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { emotionCapture } from '../actions';
import Webcam from 'react-webcam';

export default class FaceEmotion extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { screenshot: null }
        this.screenshot = this.screenshot.bind(this);
    }
    // this is the area I'm having issues with. Thanks!
    screenshot() {
        console.log(Webcam);
        var screenshot = Webcam.getScreenshot();
        this.setState({screenshot: screenshot});
      }

    render(){

        return (
            <div>   
             <Webcam audio ={false}/>
             <button onClick={this.screenshot}>Capture</button>
             { this.state.screenshot ? <img src={this.state.screenshot} /> : null }
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: What sort of issues? Errors? What happens?

Comment: I just can't use that function. I tried accessing it through different ways, but its either a undefined function or can't access that property. I'm a novice in javascript, so I don't understand the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a reference to the webcam component. This way you get the webcam that is on the screen.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { emotionCapture } from '../actions';
import Webcam from 'react-webcam';

export default class FaceEmotion extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { screenshot: null }
        // this can be moved directly to the onClick event
        // this.screenshot = this.screenshot.bind(this);
    }
    // this is the area I'm having issues with. Thanks!
    screenshot() {
        // access the webcam trough this.refs
        var screenshot = this.refs.webcam.getScreenshot();
        this.setState({screenshot: screenshot});
      }

    render(){

        return (
            <div>   
             <Webcam audio ={false} ref='webcam'/> // add the reference
             <button onClick={this.screenshot.bind(this)}>Capture</button>
             { this.state.screenshot ? <img src={this.state.screenshot} /> : null }
            </div>
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component add the following code

```
setRef = (webcam) => {
    this.webcam = webcam;
  };
```

and then use this as a reference in the render like

```
<Webcam
    audio={false}
    ref={this.setRef}
/>
```

then to capture do the following

```
this.webcam.getScreenshot();
```

this will give you a base64 encoded image string